# Getting a list by sys.argv

Tags: python

I pass mylist as an argument to be get after by sys.argv I do this:

```
mylist = str(list)
nbre = str(nbre)
comm = 'python2.6 file.py ' + mylist + ' ' + nbre + ' &'
os.system(comm)
```

In `file.py`, I am expected to get `mylist` by this way and which contains `[machine1,machine2]` but when doing:

```
mylist = sys.argv[1]
```

I get `[machine1`, which is wrong. When I display `sys.argv` I found:

```
['file.py','[machine1,','machine2]','1']
```

I didn't understand why my list is composed like that?

Comment: `list` is a [Python built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=list#list). Use another name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from this being a terrible way to communicate a list from one python script to another, you'd need to use quotes around the list to prevent it from being split by the shell:

```
comm = 'python2.6 file.py "%s" "%s" &' % (mylist, nbre)
```

I've used [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to put the quotes around `mylist` and `nbre`.

You really want to look into the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to invoke other processes without the shell getting in the way.